# Why does the same PyTorch code (different implementation) give different loss?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, pytorch

I was tackling the Fashion MNIST data-set problem on Udacity. However my implementation of code is giving drastically different loss as compared to the solution shared by the Udacity team. I believe the only difference in my answer is the definition of the Neural Network and apart from that everything is the same. I am not able to figure out the reason for such a drastic difference in Loss.

Code 1: My solution:

```
import torch.nn as nn
from torch import optim

images, labels = next(iter(trainloader))
model = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(784,256),
                 nn.ReLU(),
                 nn.Linear(256,128),
                 nn.ReLU(),
                 nn.Linear(128,64),
                 nn.ReLU(),
                 nn.Linear(64,10),
                 nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1))
# Flatten images
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(),lr=0.003)

criterion = nn.NLLLoss()

for i in range(10):
    running_loss = 0
    for images,labels in trainloader:
        images = images.view(images.shape[0], -1)
    
        output = model.forward(images)
        loss = criterion(output,labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()
    else:
        print(f"Training loss: {running_loss}")

# Loss is coming around 4000
```

Code 2: Official Solution:

```
from torch import nn, optim
import torch.nn.functional as F

class Classifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(784, 256)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 128)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(128, 64)
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(64, 10)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        # make sure input tensor is flattened
        x = x.view(x.shape[0], -1)
     
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc3(x))
        x = F.log_softmax(self.fc4(x), dim=1)
    
        return x

model = Classifier()
criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.003)
epochs = 5

for e in range(epochs):
    running_loss = 0
    for images, labels in trainloader:
        log_ps = model(images)
        loss = criterion(log_ps, labels)
    
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    
        running_loss += loss.item()
    else:
        print(f"Training loss: {running_loss}")
# Loss is coming around 200
```

Is there any explanation for the vast difference in loss ?

Comment: check the dataloader: batch size and data augmentation. Make sure they are the same.

Comment: Hi, the data-loader was exactly the same. My task was to create the model and draft the training loop. A kind fellow user pointed out that I was missing optimizer.zero_grad() from the code, which when I added back to the code Im getting similar results as compared to the original solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to zero out/clear the gradients in your implementation. That is you are missing :

```py
optimizer.zero_grad()
```

In other words simply do:

```py
for i in range(10):
    running_loss = 0
    for images,labels in trainloader:
        images = images.view(images.shape[0], -1)
    
        output = model.forward(images)
        loss = criterion(output,labels)
        # missed this! 
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()
    else:
        print(f"Training loss: {running_loss}")
```

and you are good to go!

Comment: Oh man that solved it for me. Can't believe that slipped out. Honestly thought that optimizer.zero_grad() is used only while initiating the network and since I was initiating it in the same block of code I thought its not required. Really grateful for your answer.

Comment: My pleasure :) By the way make sure you do read the official Pytorch tutorials and if possible, avoid duplicating code, were you to use the same training procedure for both networks, you'd find about the issue like in seconds rather than days. cheers